# Using sed to grep for variable and copy this with an insert text on the same line

Tags: text-processing, sed

I want to grep all `title="<text>"` variables e.g. `title="best-pencil"` and copy it on the same line as `alt="best-pencil"` within a HTML file on Linux:

```
<p class="images"><img src="my-favorite-pencil.jpg" title="best-pencil">
```

To:

```
<p class="images"><img src="my-favorite-pencil.jpg" title="best-pencil" alt="best-pencil">
```

How can this be done using `sed`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can be sure that the string will i) will always be in double quotes and will never contain `"`  and ii) always be on just one line, then it's trivial:

```
$ sed -E 's/title=("[^"]*")/& alt=\1/' file
<p class="images"><img src="my-favorite-pencil.jpg" title="best-pencil" alt="best-pencil">
```

The trick is to look for `title="` followed by 0 or more non-`"` until the next `"` and "capture" this (that's what the parentheses around `("[^"]*")` do) so we can then refer to it as `\1`. In `sed`, the `&` symbol means "whatever was matched". So, here, we are replacing `title="foo"` with itself, followed by `alt="foo"`.

If you have a `sed` version that doesn't support `-E`, you can use this instead:

```
$ sed 's/title=\("[^"]*"\)/& alt=\1/' file
<p class="images"><img src="my-favorite-pencil.jpg" title="best-pencil" alt="best-pencil">
```

Comment: sed -r -i 's/title=("[^"]*")/& alt=\1/' *.html

Comment: @roflmaowpimp yes. The `-r` is a less portable equivalent to the `-E`.

Comment: True @terdon. I use OpenBSD so `-r` is used instead of `-E`. Use `-E` for Linux-based distro's.

Comment: @roflmaowpimp openBSD sed [also supports `-E`](https://man.openbsd.org/sed). It is the `-r` that is a GNU thing, not `-E`, it's just that BSD also supports `-r` for compatibility with GNU (as explained in the man page I linked to). I use `-E` in my answers precisely so it isn't Linux-specific, like `-r`, but portable.

Comment: Thanks for making this clear @terdon!